# Teaching how to calculate a rolling average and ignore as of yet unentered data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

[image: working spreadsheet and source in excel]

This is the spreadsheet in question. The top three tables get their data from other spreadsheets in the same workbook. They are all linked together. My question pertains to the fourth table at the bottom, labeled `Annual`.

How do I have the `Annual` table calculate a rolling average?

The top three tables have formulas entered as: `=AVERAGEIF(October!L:L, "A",October!H:H)` The October spreadsheet and columns L and H are where the three tables are getting their input.

Answer (score 1):

On each of your calculations, have an `=iferror(...,"")`

Then a straight =Average(Range) will work

Bonus points: It makes your data look better

Answer (score 0):

I found that entering "=AVERAGEIF(B3:D3, "<>#DIV/0!")" is what I needed to have the calculation ignore the as of yet entered data.